# Write to existing column based on values in another column

Tags: python

Given a set of data

```
'Student ID',   'Grade',    'Weight'
'111112',       '76',       '24'
'111112',       '66',       '14'
'222223',       '46',       '14'
'333334',       '96',       '18' 
'444445',       '56',       '17'
```

How would I go through the rows to select only the "Grade" column, and write the equivalent letter grade to a new column called "Letter Grade"? What I've done so far is make the new column, but I don't know how to fill it with data calculated from the "Grade" column.

```
with open(args.source, 'rb') as source_file:
    with open(args.output, 'wb') as output_file:
        reader = csv.reader(source_file, delimiter = '\t')
        writer = csv.writer(output_file, lineterminator = '\n')
        headers = next(reader, None)

        if headers:
            writer.writerow(headers + ['Letter Grade'])

    print('Done.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_letter_grade(score):
    # define your own rules here

    if score<50:
        return "F"
    if score <60:
        return "D"
    if score<70:
        return "C"
    if score<80:
        return "B"
    return "A"

with open(args.source, 'r') as source_file, open(args.output, 'w') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, lineterminator='\n')
    reader = csv.reader(soure_file, delimiter=',')
    headers = next(reader)
    headers.append('Letter Grade')

    for row in reader:
        row = [i.strip().replace("'", '') for i in row]
        grade = int(row[1])
        letter_grade = get_letter_grade(grade)
        writer.writerow(row + [letter_grade])
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do this using a dictionary or map for comparison? Or are individual if statements the only way?

Comment: A dictionary comprehension would work, but would be more tedious. The extra function is the most pythonic way that comes to mind immediately

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to define the rule for making a `Letter Grade` out of a `Grade`. Then you can turn that rule into code. I'll use a simple one, that makes any grade >= 60 a `P`, and anything else an `F`:

```
for student_id, grade, weight in reader:
    numeric_grade = int(grade)
    letter_grade = 'P' if numeric_grade >= 60 else 'F'
    writer.writerow((student_id, grade, weight, letter_grade))
```

Whatever your actual rule is, you should be able to figure out how to write it in place of my one-liner.

If your existing code is iterating the rows in a different way—e.g., using `for row in reader:` and then relying on `row[0]` and `row[1]`—it should again be obvious how to adapt my one-liner to fit what you're doing (and to write `row + [letter_grade]`, etc.).